# ActionScript 3 Trig Equations to create Ellipse

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, trigonometry

I am working with this function that moves an object around a center point in a perfect circle and am trying to modify it to move it in an oval shape that is 1/2 as high as it is wide?

Basically, I have a set speed

```
var myVelocity:Number = 0.25;
```

then I calculate my Sine and Cosine based on the speed

```
var myCos:Number = Math.cos(myVelocity);
var mySin:Number = Math.sin(myVelocity);
```

then I figure the distance of the the object from a fixed center points along each axis and

```
var x1:Number = myBall.x - centerX;
var y1:Number = myBall.y - centerY;
var x2:Number = myCos * x1 - mySin * y1;
var y2:Number = myCos * y1 + mySin * x1;
myBall.x = centerX + x2;
myBall.y = centerY + y2;
```

I have another function that figures x and y based upon myBall.x = centerX + cos(angle) * radius; that is easy enough to modify the radius to become an ellipse, but is there an easy way to mod the one above to become an ellipse? I want to do this to be more efficient with the code and reduce the number of math function calls

Comment: It should be `var mySin:Number = Math.sin(myVelocity);`

Comment: @OXMO456: Yeah, I know, but since @user615460 is new here, I was going slow... There.  Done :)

Comment: @weltraumpirat : that is what I have :) I am trying to mod it from a circle into an ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

This question is nearly verbatim to what [Keith Peters](http://www.bit-101.com) covers in [Foundation Actionscript 3.0: Making Things Move!](http://books.google.ca/books?id=nzyu5TytMEUC&lpg=PP1&dq=actionscript%203.0%20animation&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q&f=false)

I've whipped up a quick snippet for you from the book.

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.Event;

var box:Shape = new Shape();
box.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
box.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
box.graphics.endFill();
addChild(box);
var angle:Number = 0;
var centerX:Number = stage.stageWidth/2 - (box.width/2);
var centerY:Number = stage.stageHeight/2 - (box.height/2)
var radiusX:Number = 200;
var radiusY:Number = 100;
var speed:Number = .1;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

function loop(evt:Event):void
{
    box.x = centerX + Math.sin(angle) * radiusX;
    box.y = centerY + Math.cos(angle) * radiusY;
    angle += speed;
}
```

Result: http://www.swfupload.com/view/155573.htm

Comment: thanks for this, but I already know this. I am trying to mod the code supplied to cut down on the number of math function calls. I will eventually use the code in a loop for 25 objects. If I have to call sine and cosine for every object on every reiteration it is a lot of math function calls. Since cos and sin are not changing if I could calculate it once then just iterate through the loop as supplied it will make the code run cleaner and faster. So the question is still how do I mod the code I supplied into an ellipse without using the sin and cos functions in the loop

Comment: @user615460 you just answered yourself :) ...check out 'lookup tables'...basically store sin/cos values in arrays once and use an int that will increment and jump to zero which you'll use to reference the sin/cos array values...also,without lookup tables, if you store the sin/cos values before looping through your objects, you would have 25 sin/cos calls per frame, right ?

Comment: My apologies. I did misread the last part of your question. I'd delete it, but it's spawned some useful chatter.

Comment: Figured it out myself

var x1:Number = myBall.x - myCenterX;
   var y1:Number = myY - myCenterY;
   var x2:Number = (myCos * x1) - (mySin * y1);
   var y2:Number = (myCos * y1) + (mySin * x1);
   myBall.x = myCenterX + x2;
   myY = myCenterY + y2;
   myBall.y = (myY * 0.5) + (myCenterY / 2);