# AS3 elliptical constraint for a simple slingshot

Tags: actionscript-3, ellipse

I'm trying to improve a simple AS3 slingshot that is available at http://blog.shaperstudio.com/2010/10/as3-create-a-slingshot-with-an-elastic-effect/
so that i can make it more realistic.

I already changed it so that is possible to aim the ball in any direction, but now I'm trying to create a function that constraints the maximum pull of the slingshot to an elliptical area, preferably having the same two points of the slingshot as the ellipse two focus:

```
if ( mouseX > centerX + _maximumPULL.x) _mouse_x = centerX + _maximumPULL.x;                
            else if ( mouseX < centerX - _maximumPULL.x) _mouse_x = centerX - _maximumPULL.x;
            else _mouse_x = mouseX;

if ( mouseY > centerY + _maximumPULL.y) _mouse_y = centerY + _maximumPULL.y;                
            else if ( mouseY < centerY - _maximumPULL.y) _mouse_y = centerY - _maximumPULL.y;
            else _mouse_y = mouseY;
```

In which _maximumPULL is a point variable that return us how far we can pull the elastic, something like this?:

```
_maximumPULL = new Point(200 * Math.cos(degree * Math.PI / 180), 100 * Math.sin(degree * Math.PI / 180));
```

I've been messing around with code for too many hours now and I know this is just too much for someone like me that has no background in programing, but I just can't let it go, I'm hooked...

I've been trying to understand similar problems here: http://www.soundstep.com/blog/2011/04/08/knob-as3-drag-on-circle-or-ellipse/

and here: [ActionScript 3 Trig Equations to create Ellipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986998/actionscript-3-trig-equations-to-create-ellipse)

Can you help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exactly what you're after but what about drawing the exact shape you want (be it in flash, or programatically using the `graphics` class) and then check for collision between the ball and the allowed area.

You can code that very simply by adding something like this inside your mouseMove event function:

```
if (theBall.hitTestObject( allowedRange )){
    //Put your code that figures out where the ball should be
}//otherwise, it won't alter the position of the ball :D
```